# C++ template arguments in constructor

Tags: c++, templates

Why doesn't this code compile?

```
template <class T>
class A
{
    public:
            A(T t) : t_(t) {}

    private:
            T t_;
};


int main()
{
    A a(5.5);
    // A<double> a(5.5); // that's what i don't want to do
}
```

I want template arguments to be implicit.

Like in this example:

```
template<class T>
T Foo(T t) { return t; }

// usage:
Foo(5.5);
```

**UPDATE**: named-constructor idiom isn't acceptable for me. I want to use this class for RAII.
The only way to do so is `const A& a = A::MakeA(t)`, but it's ugly!

Comment: The brief answer is "you can't". Class templates simply don't work that way. I'll leave it to someone else to try to explain the rationale.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you have to name the type of a variable (C++03 can't infer the type of a variable), you can only do:

```
A<double> a(5.5); // that's what i don't want to do
```

The situation is a little easier when you needn't make a variable of the type, but want to pass it to some other function. In this case, you define an auxiliary "constructor function" (see `std::make_pair`):

```
template <class T>
A<T> make_a(T t) { return A<T>(t); }
```

and then use it like this:

```
another_function(make_a(1.1));
```

In C++0x, you will be able to do even

```
auto a(make_a(5.5));
```

to define your variable `a`.

However, inferring `A`'s argument from its constructor is generally impossible, because you can't tell which specializations have the conversion constructor from a given type. Imagine there's a specialization

```
template <>
struct A<void>
{
  A(double);
};
```

Comment: Yet another instance of 'indirection' technique

Comment: thanx, i'll try to find another way